# How do I compare java swing button icons to check equality?

Tags: java, swing, button, comparison, equals

I am making a Tic-Tac-Toe game in Java to teach myself the Swing class. I am having to problems, though.

First, how do you compare buttons using icons?

```
symX = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("symbolX.png"));
symO = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("symbolO.png"));
```

I use those 2 variables to set the button images.

```
if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
    JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();

    if (isX) {
        source.setIcon(symX);
        source.setEnabled(false);
        source.setDisabledIcon(symX);       
    } else {    
        source.setIcon(symO);
        source.setEnabled(false);
        source.setDisabledIcon(symO);   
    }
}
```

The second question is where do you compare objects are an Action Event? I tried to compare inside of the if statements in the above code, but Eclipse always gives me compile time errors doing that.

If I place the code in the method with the buttons, it seems like java never gets to them.

As requested, here is the entirety of my Java file.

```
package ticTacToeGUI;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class tttGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9;

    private ImageIcon symX, symO;
    private ImageIcon symIco = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("symbolX.png"));
    private boolean isX = true;     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new tttGUI();
    }

    public tttGUI() {
        //Setup the window.
        super("Tic-Tac-Toe GUI 1.0");
        setSize(425,425);
        setIconImage(symIco.getImage());
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create the content.
        symX = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("symbolX.png"));
        symO = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("symbolO.png"));       

        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        setVisible(true);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton();
        JButton btn2 = new JButton();
        JButton btn3 = new JButton();
        JButton btn4 = new JButton();
        JButton btn5 = new JButton();
        JButton btn6 = new JButton();
        JButton btn7 = new JButton();
        JButton btn8 = new JButton();
        JButton btn9 = new JButton();

        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);
        btn4.addActionListener(this);
        btn5.addActionListener(this);
        btn6.addActionListener(this);
        btn7.addActionListener(this);
        btn8.addActionListener(this);
        btn9.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(btn1);
        panel.add(btn2);
        panel.add(btn3);
        panel.add(btn4);
        panel.add(btn5);
        panel.add(btn6);
        panel.add(btn7);
        panel.add(btn8);
        panel.add(btn9);

        add(panel);
        revalidate();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
            JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();

            if (isX) {
                source.setIcon(symX);
                source.setEnabled(false);
                source.setDisabledIcon(symX);       
            } else {    
                source.setIcon(symO);
                source.setEnabled(false);
                source.setDisabledIcon(symO);   
            }
        }   
        isX ^= true;    
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: What is isX? You need more context for your code. Maybe post the entire JAVA file.

Comment: I updated with the entire Java file, also isX is the boolean I use to determine which symbols turn it is. I tried comparing the btns like this:   if(btn1.getIcon().equals(symX) && btn2.getIcon().equals(symX)  etc, but if i put it at the end of tttGUI it did nothing and if I put it in the Action Listener it did nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is two years too late, but other people in the future might find this useful...

Anyway, coincidentally I'm programming up 3D Tic Tac Toe.
To compare `ImageIcons`, I initialized the Icons with a `String` description, and then used:

```
((ImageIcon) JLabel().getIcon()).getDescription().compareTo("someOtherDesc")
```

Hope that helps you or someone else in future...

Answer (score 1):

I have some ideas on how to do that, for instance:

```
symX = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("symbolX.png"));
symO = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("symbolO.png"));

if (btn1.getIcon().equals(symX) && btn2.getIcon().equals(symX) {
    // Your logic here...
}
```

This can be done inside you `actionPerformed()` method if you promote your local variables `btn1...btn9` to instance variables. It seems you mixed up concepts since you already have `btn1...btn9` declared as instance variables, but also create new ones as local variables.

```
public class TttGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JButton btn1 = new JButton();
    private JButton btn2 = new JButton();
    private JButton btn3 = new JButton();
    private JButton btn4 = new JButton();
    private JButton btn5 = new JButton();
    private JButton btn6 = new JButton();
    private JButton btn7 = new JButton();
    private JButton btn8 = new JButton();
    private JButton btn9 = new JButton();

    private ImageIcon symX, symO;
    private ImageIcon symIco = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("symbolX.png"));
    private boolean isX = true;     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TttGUI();
    }

    public TttGUI() {
        //Setup the window.
        super("Tic-Tac-Toe GUI 1.0");
        setSize(425,425);
        setIconImage(symIco.getImage());
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create the content.
        symX = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("symbolX.png"));
        symO = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("symbolO.png"));       

        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        setVisible(true);

        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);
        btn4.addActionListener(this);
        btn5.addActionListener(this);
        btn6.addActionListener(this);
        btn7.addActionListener(this);
        btn8.addActionListener(this);
        btn9.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(btn1);
        panel.add(btn2);
        panel.add(btn3);
        panel.add(btn4);
        panel.add(btn5);
        panel.add(btn6);
        panel.add(btn7);
        panel.add(btn8);
        panel.add(btn9);

        add(panel);
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

I have changed your class name so that it is compliant to Java conventions (class names must always start with capital case).

Comment: I still don't understand where to put this code. If I put any more code into my listener method, it just errors out. If I put it at the end of tttGUI, it doesn't reach it. I'm not sure how to add the check portion of the code into a listener.

Comment: What do you want do to after comparing the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Though it is too late but anyone who search may get help in comparing imageicons.I think it is very easy to campare

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/myimage.jpg");

    JLabel a = new JLabel(icon);

    JLabel b = new JLabel(icon);



    if(a.getIcon().toString().equals(b.getIcon().toString()))
    {
      //do whatever
    }
```