# How do I compare the ImageIcon in a JButton and an ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton, imageicon

I want to compare two icons (one is the icon set to the button and the other is an image icon declared just above the if statement. Java gives me null pointer exception for the comparison. what's the problem? (Is it a syntax error? am I using an incorrect method for comparing the icons?)

```
    final ImageIcon x=new ImageIcon("X.png");
    final ImageIcon o=new ImageIcon("O.png");

    if(jbutton[0][0].getIcon().equals(x)&& jbutton [1][0].getIcon().equals(x)&& jbutton[2][0].getIcon().equals(x)) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "insert message here");
        hasWinner=(true);
    }
    else if (jbutton[0][1].getIcon().equals(x)&& jbutton [1][1].getIcon().equals(x)&& jbutton[2][1].getIcon().equals(x))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "insert message here");
        hasWinner=(true);
    }
```

Comment: I already read that, but it didn't really help with my question, I'm looking for a method to compare two icons

Comment: Why is guess work as we don't have enough context to go by.  I'd suggest though, this approach is a bad idea. Instead you should determine row/column the button represents and look up a value in a predefined model. There are lots of ways you could achieve this

Comment: is my comparison method correct though? that was my primary concern

Comment: That would depend on the implementation of `ImageIcon#equals`, which is why I'd personally avoid it

Comment: How about [this as an alterntive duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353218/how-do-i-compare-java-swing-button-icons-to-check-equality)

Comment: If I reopened it, I'd vote to close with question I posted in comments, either way, it should be closed